# Selector memoized returned the root state when called. Redux-ToolKit

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit

I'm using useSelector of reduxtoolkit and everytime I run my app. My app re-renders 5 times and I keep on getting this error. I cant seem to find a way too get rid of this error.

Selector memoized returned the root state when called. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders.
Selectors that return the entire state are almost certainly a mistake, as they will cause a rerender whenever *anything* in state changes.

[image: Image Of Error]

**AppNavigator.tsx**

```
const AppNavigator: FC<Props> = props => {
  const {loggedIn, busy} = useSelector(getAuthState);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log('render');
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAuthInfo = async () => {
      try {
        dispatch(updateBusyState(true));
        const token = await getFromAsyncStorage(Keys.AUTH_TOKEN);
        if (!token) {
          return dispatch(updateBusyState(false));
        }

        const {data} = await client.get('/auth/is-auth', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
          },
        });
        dispatch(updateProfile(data.profile));
        dispatch(updateLoggedInState(true));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Auth error: ', error);
      }
      dispatch(updateBusyState(false));
    };
    fetchAuthInfo();
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={AppTheme}>
      {busy ? (
        <View
          style={{
            ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
            backgroundColor: colors.OVERLAY,
            zIndex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <Loader />
        </View>
      ) : null}
      {loggedIn ? <TabNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

**Slice.tsx**

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateProfile(authState, {payload}: PayloadAction<UserProfile | null>) {
      authState.profile = payload;
    },
    updateLoggedInState(authState, {payload}) {
      authState.loggedIn = payload;
    },
    updateBusyState(authState, {payload}: PayloadAction<boolean>) {
      authState.busy = payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {updateLoggedInState, updateProfile, updateBusyState} =
  slice.actions;

export const getAuthState = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state,
  ({auth}) => auth,
);

export default slice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For something like you are doing here, you really do not need (and should not use) `createSelector`.

Instead of

```js
export const getAuthState = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state,
  ({auth}) => auth,
);
```

you can just write

```
export const getAuthState = (state: RootState) => state.auth;
```

`createSelector` is only necessary when your selector is doing heavy computation or creating a new object.

Also, you should not do something like

```js
const {loggedIn, busy} = useSelector(getAuthState);
```

That will also rerender when `state.auth.profile.lastName`(or, really, anything else in `state.auth`) changes.

Instead, do

```js
const loggedIn = useSelector(rootState => getAuthState(rootState).loggedIn);
const busy = useSelector(rootState => getAuthState(rootState).busy);
```

Comment: PS: that said, you should only ever get this error when you call `useSelector(state => state)` somewhere. Are you sure you are not doing that anywhere too?

Comment: How exactly does redux compare previous state with the current one in order to rerender? I have read from doc that its done via `===` operator, but what are its operands? previous state (how exactly is stored) and current one?

Comment: @milanHrabos The moment it gets a new selector result it still knows the old one, so it literally does `newResult === result` to compare them.

Comment: sounds about right

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't give a name, back to your store index file add `auth` as a name:

**store/index.ts**

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
  auth: authReducer
  },
});
```

**store/auth.ts**

```js
 export const getAuthState = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.auth,
  authState => authState,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`create-react-app` with `react-typescript-router` template had the following in generated `supports/Persistence.tsx` file

```
const state = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state)
const count = String(state.counter.value)
```

Which caused the following error to popup in the browser console

```
Selector unknown returned the root state when called. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders.
Selectors that return the entire state are almost certainly a mistake, as they will cause a rerender whenever *anything* in state changes.
```

Don't deal with the whole root state in Persistence.tsx, changing it to the following should make the error go away

```
const count = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter.value)
```